# Gerar números aleatórios em 2d numpy array sem repetir Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy, array-multidimensional

Boa tarde, estou tentando fazer gerar um 2d  numpy array sem numeros repetidos.
Meu codigo:

```
TAMANHO = 4
tabela= np.zeros((TAMANHO, TAMANHO), dtype = int)
tabela[:, 0] = np.random.randint(1, 170, TAMANHO)
tabela[:, 1] = np.random.randint(1, 170, TAMANHO)
tabela[:, 2] = np.random.randint(1, 170, TAMANHO)
tabela[:, 3] = np.random.randint(1, 170, TAMANHO)
tabela
```

Por exemplo em vez de eu gerar esse conjunto de array 2D com numero repetido:

```
array([[ 50,  39, 120, 129],
       [143, 147, 127,  82],
       [ 39,  63, 138,  48],
       [ 34,  63, 114, 119]])
```

Gostaria de gerar aleatoriamente sem repeteir nenhum numero.

Alguem me ajuda?

Comment: Eu sabia fazer assim: `tabela = np.random.random_integers(170, size=(4,4))` mas estou tomando aviso de depreciação nessa função `random_integers()`

Comment: e se for para valores como 10 de inicio e 170 de final? colocava em aparentese?

Comment: Não é bom ir por esse caminho pois a função foi depreciada e logo vai deixar de funcionar. Deixei o comentário pois também quero saber a resposta.

Comment: ok, vou deixa sim

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar [`numpy.random.Generator.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.choice.html#numpy.random.Generator.choice):

```
from numpy.random import default_rng

rng = default_rng()
numbers = rng.choice(range(1, 171), size=(4, 4), replace=False)
```

Usei `range(1, 171)` para que os números escolhidos estejam entre 1 e 170 (em um [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range), o valor final não é incluso, por isso tenho que passar `171`). E o argumento `replace=False` indica que não pode haver valores repetidos.

---

Vale lembrar que, por não ter repetição de valores, o `range` deve ter elementos suficientes para preencher todas as posições. Por exemplo, o caso abaixo dá erro:

```
numbers = rng.choice(range(10), size=(4, 4), replace=False)
```

Como `range(10)` só tem 10 valores possíveis (os números entre 0 e 9) e eu quero gerar um array 4 x 4 (ou seja, com 16 valores) sem repetição, o código acima dá um erro:

> ValueError: Cannot take a larger sample than population when 'replace=False'

Se eu usasse `replace=True`, não daria erro, mas aí o array resultante teria números repetidos.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi, você deseja implementar uma matriz na qual todos os seus valores estejam sem estar **repetidos**.

Observe que quando estamos trabalhando com matrizes temos de deixar claro o **número de linhas e colunas**.

Pois bem, para resolvermos esta questão podemos utiliza o seguinte código:

```
import numpy as np
from random import sample

m = int(input('Digite o número de linhas: '))
n = int(input('Digite o número de colunas: '))
v = (m * n)

# Montando uma matriz qualquer.
if v <= 170:
    numeros = sample(range(1, 171), v)
    print(np.array([numeros[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(numeros), n)]))
else:
    print('Erro! Quantidade de sorteios maiores que o range!')
```

Quando executamos o referido código recebemos a primeira mensagem: `Digite o número de linhas:` . Neste momento devemos digitar o número de linhas de nossa matriz e pressionar `enter`. Em seguida, recebemos a segunda mensagem: `Digite o número de colunas:` . Neste momento devemos digitar o número de colunas e pressionar `enter`.

Observe que o bloco **if** controlará a quantidade de elementos da matriz. Caso esta quantidade seja **menor ou igual** ao limite superior do range, a matriz será montada e exibida. Caso contrário, receberemos uma mensagem de erro que diz: `Erro! Quantidade de sorteios maiores que o range!`. Este erro nos diz que queremos gerar uma matriz com uma quantidade de elementos maior que o range suportado.

Se os valores digitados satisfizerem o range arbitrado, o código montará uma lista com nome de **numeros**, contendo **(m * n)** elementos sorteados do **range(1, 171)**.

**Observação 1:** Utilizei o **range(1, 171)**, porque sabemos que o range no python sempre vai de **1 até n - 1**. Então, para sortear valores dentro do intervalo fechado [1, 170], deve definir o range como **range(1, 171)**.

**Observação 2:** Quando indico o número de linhas - **m** - e o número de colunas - **n** - o número total de valores sorteado será **(m * n)**.

Após o sorteio dos valores os mesmos serão organizados e exibidos

**Vamos testar o código?**

Criar uma matriz que tenha **4** linhas e **4** colunas, na qual cada elemento seja sorteado aleatoriamente do intervalo fechado **[1, 170]**.

Para resolver este exemplo, devemos executar o código, digitar o valor **4** -  para o número de linhas - e pressionar `enter`, digitar o valor **4** - para o número de colunas - e pressionar `enter`.

A partir deste momento o código irá montar e apresentar uma matriz de ordem **4 x 4** - com 16 valores - com valores sorteados **sem repetições**.